# Express - Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Tags: express, request

When I test my application with siege `siege -b -r 1 -c 100 https://*****/RTC/stats/rank`

I get this error in my nodeJS console

```
_http_outgoing.js:491
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/nodeJS/RTC-stats/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/nodeJS/RTC-stats/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/nodeJS/RTC-stats/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/nodeJS/RTC-stats/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at Request._callback (/home/nodeJS/RTC-stats/server.js:46:14)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/nodeJS/RTC-stats/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
```

Here you can find the code I used:

```
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

let players = [
  "df6c767a-c4a9-4a42-bbbc-e34c7b4f1e16",
  "22366c4f-744a-422b-81ff-e21608dd5950",
  "c553f6b4-da31-4879-88a6-5dfa28cae1ac",
  "5e5cfb2e-29a5-407e-972b-9999fcd567af",
  "5fcc4c0e-13ca-49d2-a949-b74ef17d146f",
  "094fd818-f794-404c-a2a4-674d3be5e7d3",
];
let responses = [];

let completed_requests = 0;

app.get('/RTC/stats/rank', function (ereq, eres) {
  for (var i = 0, len = players.length; i < len; i++) {
    var playerUUID = players[i];
    var options = {
      url: 'https://r6db.com/api/v2/players/' + playerUUID + '?platform=PC',
      headers: {
        'x-app-id': '5e23d930-edd3-4240-b9a9-723c673fb648'
      },
    };
    request(options, function(err, res, body) {
      if (err) { return console.log(err); }
      var playerInfo = JSON.parse(body);
      responses.push(playerInfo.rank.emea);
      completed_requests++;
      if (completed_requests === players.length) {
        completed_requests = 0;
        eres.send(responses);
        responses = [];
      }
    });
  }
});

app.listen(3000)
```

I think there is a problem with the way I send the request to the api. My biggest gues is that it has to do with timing and the sending of the result back to the client. Or is using siege a bad way of testing this application.

Comment: `eres.send(responses);` needs to change. You send a response every time in the for loop which is an issue. I think that you should go ahead and move the `eres` code to outside of the for loop, then you will no longer get this error. You will also need to make this more promise oriented to make this work instead of callbacks. I will maybe write up an answer to help fit your request.

Comment: Also, I would recommend that you take the time to use env variables instead of static strings like that if you are pushing the code to github or posting it on stack for help due to security of your keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const players = [];

app.get(`/`, async (ereq, eres) => {

    const http = (options) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request(options, (err, res, body) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                return resolve(JSON.parse(body));
            });
        });
    };



    for(let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {

        var playerUUID = players[i];
        var options = {
            url: 'https://r6db.com/api/v2/players/' + playerUUID + '?platform=PC',
            headers: {
                'x-app-id': '5e23d930-edd3-4240-b9a9-723c673fb648'
            },
        };

        try {
            let playerInfo = await http(options);
            response.push(playerInfo.rank.emea);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e); // I think that you should handle this a better way than just console.logging...
        }
    }

    return eres.json(response);
});
```

Just make sure that you use promises. Promises will slow down the for loop in order for you to get a proper response and also allowing you to check whatever you need to before returning. If you need to return a response in the for loop, then I would recommend that you go ahead and `break;` out of the for loop before it continues to try and send data to a response that is already sent.